# How do I run vm in aws instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

Here is something I wanted to accomplish.

I would be required to create a virtual machine on virtual box in aws instance. After setting this up, I should be able to export the virtual machine created, to any other parties which would require them to run in their own server.

I am some what familiar with aws stuff, but not quite sure was it even possible to accomplish the task I wanted?

Any suggestions on how could it be done?

Comment: wait. what what? what do you want to do again?

Comment: To make it simple, I want to create a vm in aws. If I could do it, we will go with detail in later :)

Comment: If you want to create a vm on virtualbox, why do you want to pay AWS for it? You can do it for free on any laptop/desktop and export the image. AWS on the other hand can directly provide you a VM without dealing with VirtualBox.

Comment: The thing is I already got 2 vm running on my local host, and could get really slow if I try one more. So I choose with using aws running the vm for me. Suggest me how that could be done in a better way.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot run Oracle VirtualBox inside an EC2 instance. The Xen Hypervisor does not provide access to the underlying hardware for VirtualBox. When you start VirtualBox you will receive an error message "Running VirtualBox in a Xen environment is not supported".

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand how VM works, to boot a VM, you need a virtual machine manager(VMM) which is also called as a hypervisor. There are 2 types of [Hypervisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor), Type I and Type II.

Type I is your Oracle virtual box which needs an operating system to run.
Type II is hosted in a data center and runs on a Hardware, its mostly used for commercial purpose. [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#ec2-hypervisor) provides it as a service. So, you don't need to maintain a hypervisor.

If your goal is to build a Virtual Box, use packer, get an ec2 instance or any other server to run your packer builds.

https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/virtualbox-iso.html

> The builder builds a virtual machine by creating a new virtual machine
>   from scratch, booting it, installing an OS, provisioning software
>   within the OS, then shutting it down. The result of the VirtualBox
>   builder is a directory containing all the files necessary to run the
>   virtual machine portably.